# C++: conflicing overloads in template and "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope" errors

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, constructor-overloading

I've nested a template in a class `message` which usually contains a subclass of `message`, but if I want it contain `message` itself, I run into problems of conflicting ctor overloads. (It would be good if I could somehow get it to ignore one of the conflicting methods, but I don't know how.) So I try to make a specialization of the `messsage` containee, but then I get

> explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class message'

I've researched how to deal with errors like that (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097811/c-syntax-for-explicit-specialization-of-a-template-function-in-a-template-clas), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777236/gcc-error-explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714665/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-error-desperately-need-help)) but I can't figure out how to shoehorn those solutions into my problem.

```
class message {
    template<class T>
    class sptrTemplate : public QSharedPointer<T>
    {
    public:
        sptrTemplate() : QSharedPointer<T>() {}
        sptrTemplate(T *msg_ptr) : QSharedPointer<T>(msg_ptr) {}
        sptrTemplate(message *msg_ptr) : QSharedPointer<T>(static_cast<T *>(msg_ptr)) {}
    };
};
```

Remember, `T` is usually a subclass of `message`. The only exception is when `T` *is* `message`. Then, there's an obvious conflict between the 2nd and 3rd ctor. But if I try specializing with

```
    template <>
    class sptrTemplate<message> : public QSharedPointer<message>
    {
    public:
        sptr() : QSharedPointer<message>() {}
        sptr(message *msg_ptr) : QSharedPointer<message>(msg_ptr) {}
    };
```

then I get that compiler error, and I can't figure out how to deal with that.

Comment: Your link here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5777270/597607 has the exact solution to the problem. Note that you have to use `message::sptrTemplate` when specializing outside the `message`class.

Comment: @BoPersson Funny, I tried that before, and it didn't work. It seems I didn't know how to properly express the namespace.